# S4 object inheriting from data.frame: remove warning in dplyr::filter

Tags: r, inheritance, dplyr, r-s4

I have an S4 class that inherits from data.frame:

```
> setClass("Foo", contains="data.frame")
> x <- new("Foo", data.frame(a=1:2))
```

Now `dplyr::filter` works but issues a warning:

```
> x %>% dplyr::filter(a > 1)
  a
1 2
Warning message:
In class(x) <- c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame") :
  Setting class(x) to multiple strings ("tbl_df", "tbl", ...); result
  will no longer be an S4 object
```

Is there any good way to get rid of this warning?  I can create a new
generic of `filter`, and wrap the dplyr version in this something
like

```
dplyr::filter(as.data.frame(unclass(x)), ...)
```

but isn't the point with inheritance to avoid such extra work?

Is this warning related to dplyr not being aware of S4 objects?

Edit: same behavior for dplyr 0.4.3 and 0.5.0

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` utilises the tibble package, where a conversion from a data.frame to a tibble takes place which assigns three classes to the argument. `unclass()` is called before this, but unclass'ing does *not* strip the object of its status as being an S4 object, and so the warning above occurs.

In short, this is a problem within `dplyr`. I think you would have to make wrappers for the generics.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect dplyr (and data.table and maybe more) just ignores the object being S4.  Should probably take it up at github.

Comment: Yeah, it'll have to be raised there. Or with any luck someone else figures out a simple workaround. I've only just started using S4 and am still not sure what is possible.